# ios/objective-c/storyboard: How to connect label in view controller in Storyboard to outlet in core class

Tags: ios, storyboard, iboutlet

I have a core view class that does much of the logic for more than one View Controller.  Originally to wire this up, I assigned the class to the view controller.  Later, however, I changed the class for the view controller to a different class (actually a sub-class of the core class) that had some custom features just for it.

Now I want to add another property to more than one view controller.  The logical place to put the property is in the core class.  However, I'm reluctant to rename the class for the View Controller as I don't want to mess up all the other links that are currently there.

Is there a way to wire up a View Controller label to a property in a class that is not the current class for that View Controller?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that. You have a `CoreView` and then you have `SubCoreView : CoreView`. Then you want to wire a `UILabel` which is a child view in view hierarchy of the `SubCoreView`. But you want to add the label property to be in the `CoreView`.

I think you just need to define the label manually in the CoreView class.

```
@interface CoreView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

Then you just connect the label to the core view in storyboard like this
[image]

you should find the label as in the following:[image]

Comment: I have created the property manually.  When I ctrl click on the label, I do see the Referencing outlets.  However when I click on plus nothing happens.   And I can't seem to make any connection between the label and the property.

Comment: You don't click on the plus. You click on the label which has a black background.